How can I make char string array in C have dynamic size?
C language
I'm writing a function that relies later on on generating some text that has to hold the length of essentially: 115 letters minus the length of substring within <> from the original argument to the function - (115 - substring length).
However, C doesn't accept char text[value] with dynamic value, and I need it in that code to be dynamic and dependent on how large the size of extracted substring was.
How can I do that?
char* RandomText(char* originalMsg)
{
    char* subString;
    char msgClone[256];
    strcpy(msgClone, originalMsg);
    subString = strtok(msgClone, "<");
    subString = strtok(NULL, ">"); 

    int spewageSize = 115 - strlen(subString); //110 + safe buffer for \n and \0

    char text[spewageSize]; 

    // the rest of the code follows here
}


What you coded is supported by compilers that support VLAs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array You just can't change the size of char text[spewSize] once you define it. Unless, it's scoped inside a loop (e.g.) for (spewSize = 10;  spewSize < 1000;  ++spewSize) { char text[spewSize]; // stuff ... } Or, use a pointer: char *text = malloc(sizeof(*text) * spewSize); You have to do free(text); but it can take much larger arrays as stack space is limited (e.g. 8 MB).

Just make the array with size 115.  Any overhead is negligible.


How can I do that?

Do not write code that assumes small string lengths.
Negate the need for char msgClone[256]; and strtok().
Allocate memory.

Use strcspn() to find the offset of the "<" and ">".

//                   v---v note the const
char* RandomText_Alt(const char* originalMsg) {
    size_t open_offset = strcspn(originalMsg, "<");
    const char *substring = &originalMsg[open_offset];
    if (*substring) substring++;

    size_t close_offset = strcspn(substring, ">"); 

    // Limit sub-string length if desired.
    if (close_offset >= 115) {
      close_offset = 115 - 1;
    }

    char *text = malloc(close_offset + 1);
    if (text) {
      memcpy(text, substring, close_offset);
      text[close_offset] = '\0';

      // The rest of the code follows here.

      free(text);
    }
...


"1." implies there will be a "2." Did you change your mind about showing multiple solutions?

@Barmar, OP'a code is RandomText().  This answer's code is RandomText_Alt() is a replacement for RandomText().  A different name is used to disambiguate.

All good C compilers have VLA (variable length array) support and your code will be compiled without error.
However, in recent C standards VLA support is optional; so you should either allocate dynamically, or calculate maximum array size that you might need.
In your case it is easy to see that your VLA size is actually limited to 115:
char* RandomText(char* originalMsg)
{
    char* subString;
    char msgClone[256];
    if (sizeof(msgClone) < strlen(originalMsg) + 1) {
        return NULL; // handle error here
    }
    strcpy(msgClone, originalMsg);
    subString = strtok(msgClone, "<");
    subString = strtok(NULL, ">"); 

    int spewageSize = 115 - strlen(subString); //110 + safe buffer for \n and \0

    char text[115];
    if ((int)sizeof(text) < spewageSize) {
        return NULL; // handle error here
    }

    // the rest of the code follows here

}

If you are not certain about sizes, you can always allocate dynamically:
char* RandomText(char* originalMsg)
{
    char* subString;
    char* msgClone = (char*)malloc(strlen(originalMsg) + 1);
    if (msgClone == NULL) {
        return NULL; // handle error here
    }
    strcpy(msgClone, originalMsg);
    subString = strtok(msgClone, "<");
    subString = strtok(NULL, ">"); 

    if (strlen(subString) >= 115) {
        free(msgClone);
        return NULL; // handle error here
    }

    int spewageSize = 115 - strlen(subString); //110 + safe buffer for \n and \0

    char* text = (char*)malloc(spewageSize);
    if (text == NULL) {
        free(msgClone);
        return NULL; // handle error here
    }

    // the rest of the code follows here
    //free(text);
    //free(msgClone);
}

I commented out free calls, because I don't know about your program logic.
If you don't use those memories at the end of function, you should call free functions.

If the standard says VLAs are optional, it seems odd to say a compiler is good or bad based on whether it supports them or not.

@Chris Making VLAs optional in C11 was a mistake by the C committee, because while VLA allocation in itself is mildly useful, pointers to VLA is very handy to have. A pointer to a VLA is compatible with a pointer to an array with fixed since, so they allow interfaces like void func (size_t n, int array[n]) which is great for type safety, reducing code repetition, sensible dynamic allocation of multi-dimensional arrays etc etc. The committee realized that because of this, making VLA optional was a hasty and incorrect decision. ->

Therefore in upcoming C23, this form of parameter VLA declaration is once again mandatory for all C compilers.

@Chris As for MSVC being bad - it stubbornly insists on being non-compatible with the C language so it is bad for that very reason. It didn't support VLA before C11, it didn't support VLA after C11 and it will not support VLA after C23. In fact it doesn't even support ISO 9899:Amd1:1995. Meaning that for example Windows 95 a more modern Micosoft product than the latest MSVC.

I didn't disagree with anything you said, @Lundin. I just think the wording in the answer could use work. It feels very much like Microsoft treats C as a subset of C++, rather than a distinct language.

@Chris Rather: Microsoft treats C as a necessary evil to conform with certain parts of C++ where the languages are identical. This was their only motivation for upgrading the C compiler to cover "a little bit of C99 and C11" a few years back.

Ali Farzanrad, Good that tests were added to code.  Yet int spewageSize = 115 - strlen(subString); remains a potential pitfall.  Suggest if (strlen(subString) >= 115) Handle_Error(); int spewageSize = 115 - strlen(subString); or the like.  Tests like if ((int)sizeof(text) < spewageSize) { are too late.

@chux-ReinstateMonica I don't see any problem in late validation.  strlen(subString) is much lower than int boundaries, so 115 - strlen(subString) will never underflow.  Beside hard-coding 115 more than that isn't seem to be a good practice.

@AliFarzanrad "115 - strlen(subString) will never underflow." --> There is nothing in the code of your RandomText() that prevents the sub-string between < and > from being longer than 115 characters - certainly not the comment "//110 + safe buffer for \n and \0".  Perhaps in your usage of  RandomText(), calling code does not present an overly long string, yet for RandomText() to rely on that is brittle.

@chux-ReinstateMonica you are right, at the second code with dynamic allocation there was no guarantee on string length.

As noted in comments, compilers that support variable length arrays will do this. Notably, GCC does, and Clang does as well for compatibility, while MSVC does not.
However, memory is cheap, so allocate plenty of space for strings. If the maximum you know you'll need is 115, just use that. Or even allocate more space. Your compiler may for alignment purposes anyway.
If you want a duplicate of another string and that string needs to be returned from a function, you may wish to use strdup.

Beware that strdup() is not standard C.
